# How to center the title of my artwork on the artboard?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need to give a title to my artwork. Unfortunately, the arboard is randomly extended during the process and how I am wondering how to center the title of my artwork which is written at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Have you considered centring it manually, so it looks centred under the circle above, even though it may not be actually centred on the artboard?

Comment: Thank you, Billy. Yes, I tried to cenred it manually and it does not look centered with respect with artboard.

Comment: I think it will look better centred under the circle.  Few people will notice it's not exactly at the centre of the page unless they were to use a ruler.  Either that, or fix the placement of all the items, so that the middle circle is dead centre, then you can put the text in the dead centre too.

Comment: Why not add the title when you are done extending the artboard? Or always extend the artboard in both ends so the center doesn't move?

Comment: Is there some reason selecting the text and hitting align center to artboard isn't possible?

Comment: @Scott, thank you, it worked through alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- From the Menu Bar click Window > Align. 
2- A window similar to this one will appear[image: Aligne Tool]

3- Click on the bottom right corner and a drop-down menu will appear.
4- Make sure the option **Align to Artboard** is checked.
5- Select your text and choose the button that looks like two rectangles above each other and a line goes through their center.
[image: Align Centers Horezontaily icon]

this is the **Horizontal Align Center** option. This basically aligns objects horizontally.

Comment: thank your for your answer. It helped me to complete my work. Have a nice day.